# heroku Getting at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/test" service=28795ms status=503

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, heroku

I am getting this error in a spring boot app which works perfectly in local
I connect the heroku app remotely to the database of my own server.
It is deployed susscessfully but I could not get a response

at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/test" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28795ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTTP error code. Try to check your error code out here [heroku error code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response)